# connect switch to cable modem

Tags: wireless-router, switch, cable-modem

Can I run a splitter(switch) from Cable modem to switch to router?  I want to place my wireless router in a different room from my modem but connect my desktop and printer in the same room as my modem.

Comment: Give some more details.

Answer (score 1):

You should connect the switch to the inside (LAN) port of the router. Connecting it in between router (WAN port) and modem would require any device connected to the switch to create its own Internet session - which may not be supported by your ISP.

You'll need either a 2nd wireless router (actually just an access point) or run back a LAN cable from the router to the switch.